# Iterating though list of objects in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I've a list of objects that I'm getting through repository and service. I'm trying to iterate over each object when trying to through response.

```
JSONArray response = new JSONArray();

List < Object[] > ratings = new ArrayList < > ();

ratings = ratingService.getListOfSeller("active");

List < Object[] > objects = ratings;

if (objects.size() > 0) {

    for (Object object: objects) {
        JSONObject response2 = new JSONObject();
        response2.put("sellerID", objects.get(0)[1]);
        response.put(response2);
    }

} else {
    response = new JSONArray();
}
```

This snippet giving me the same results for the number of iterations. how can I iterate through each object from objects.get(0)[1]

tried this one too, but gives an error.

```
if (objects.size() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject response2 = new JSONObject();
        response2.put("sellerID", objects.get(i)[i]);
        response.put(response2);
    }
} else {
    response = new JSONArray();
}
```

> error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2`

Comment: `objects.get(0)` returns an array with a length of `1`. You are accessing index `1` which is the **second** index.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
List<Object[]> ratings = new ArrayList<>();
JSONObject response2 = null;

for (Object[] objects : ratings) { //will loop through ratings List
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) { //will loop through object array
        response2 = new JSONObject();
        response2.put("sellerID", objects[i]);
        response.put(response2);
    }
}
```

Comment: this does give the solution, though I'm getting an extra data for each data, 
`[
    {
        "sellerID": "com.Model.User@7b3c0a81"
    },
    {
        "sellerID": 4.5
    },
    {
        "sellerID": "com.Model.User@3dd4d86d"
    },
    {
        "sellerID": 4.5
    },
    {
        "sellerID": "com.Model.User@6db6adb5"
    },
    {
        "sellerID": 3.5
    }
]`

Comment: If you need to exclude mentioned `com.Model.User` objects add extra conditional check before putting object into response. `if(!(objects[i] instanceof com.Model.User)) response.put("sellerID", objects[i]);` this will exclude `{ "sellerID": "com.Model.User@7b3c0a81" }` this output.